# Real time voice changing with Python

Tags: python, audio, audio-streaming, voice

I'm going to make a Python program to change the voice in Discord, Teamspeak and similar programs. So far I don't know where to start, because I haven't found any guides on the Internet. After searching for various examples on github I came across this:

```py
import numpy

import soundcard
from pysndfx import AudioEffectsChain


default_speaker = soundcard.default_speaker()
default_mic = soundcard.default_microphone()


data = default_mic.record(samplerate=44100, numframes=44100)
default_speaker.play(data/numpy.max(data), samplerate=48000)

fx = (
    AudioEffectsChain()
    .speed(factor=0.8)
    .reverb(reverberance=100, hf_damping=50, pre_delay=10)
)

with default_mic.recorder(samplerate=44100) as mic, default_speaker.player(samplerate=48000) as sp:
    while True:
        data = mic.record(numframes=1024)
        data = fx(numpy.array(data))
        sp.play(data)
```

but this example gives me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\vc\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    data = fx(numpy.array(data))
  File "E:\Projects\vc\venv\lib\site-packages\pysndfx\dsp.py", line 413, in __call__
    stdout, stderr = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate(stdin.tobytes(order="F"))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Cannot find specified file

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would be happy to get a simple code example and maybe some tips. Thanks.

Comment: The pysndfx package looks deprecated: https://github.com/carlthome/python-audio-effects.